# Two body decay & four momentum

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics

The 4 momentum of a particle is given by $P=(M,\vec 0)$, and it decays into two daughters with $p_1$ and $p_2$. Then $P=p_1+p_2$ and 
$$p_2^2 = (P-p_1)^2 = P^2 -2P.p_1 +p_1^2$$
How do you get from this line to the fact that
$$m_2^2 = M^2 -2ME_1 +m_1^2$$
It's something to do with being in the rest frame of the parent but I don't understand how to get from the equation with momenta to the one with masses.

Comment: [Possibly helpful](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html#c3)

Answer (score 3):

Very silly question. In particular the part I couldn't work out was why $P.p_1 = ME_1$ but the four vector $P$ is $(M,0,0,0)$ as we are in the rest frame of that particle, and $p_1 = (E_1, p_x, p_y, p_z)$ and the dot product of those is clearly $ME_1$.